# ordered vs unordered sample space

Tags: probability

> In the game of bridge, the entire deck of 52 cards is dealt out to 4
> players. What is the probability that each player receives 1 ace?

I tried to solve this problem by trying to solve what I thought was an isomorphic problem: Given 4 aces and 4 people, what is the probability all 4 people get an Ace. First question, this isn't an isomorphic problem because the constraint of 13 cards each, right?

Regardless, I want to solve the second problem since something isn't quite right when I try to solve with ordered vs unordered sample spaces. (I've been told they're the same way of viewing the same situation.)

Answer for the ordered POV: $4!/4^4$ because $A_1$ has 4 choices, and for each choice, $A_2$ has 3 choices, etc.

Answer for unordered POV: $1/\binom{7}{3}$ by "Stars and Bars"

Where am I messing up?

Comment: As an aside, the probability of one ace to each player when dealing all $52$ cards, you could go the long way and call this $\dfrac{4\binom{48}{12}\cdot 3\binom{36}{12}\cdot 2\binom{24}{12}\cdot 1\cdot \binom{12}{12}}{\binom{52}{13,13,13,13}}$, but it would be easier to imagine each slot in each person's hand and distribute the cards in order to random slots (*rather than random cards into slots in order*) giving $1\cdot \frac{39}{51}\cdot\frac{26}{50}\cdot\frac{13}{49}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two problems you described are not isomorphic for the reason you stated.

Your first solution to the second problem is correct.

The problem with your second attempt is that the $\binom{7}{3}$ unordered distributions are not equally likely to occur.  For instance, there is only one way for a particular player to receive all four aces, but there are $4!$ ways for each player to receive an ace.

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to solve the first problem, but I think maybe I'm making the same mistake as my second attempt. I have $$\frac{\frac{48!}{4!(12!)^4}}{\frac{52!}{4!(13!)^4}}$$ Here, I only care about the divisions themselves, not which player gets which hand, i.e. ABCD = BACD = ACDB, etc. I also don't care about the order of the aces, they're all the same, so we just give one to each player, and thus multiply by 1, and not 4!

Comment: I know how to do the ordered version: $\frac{\frac{48!}{(12!)^4}}{\frac{52!}{(13!)^4}} * 4!$ but I don't know why the unordered version is wrong.

Comment: See my solution to this problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2521017/probability-of-deck-of-cards-such-that-each-person-receives-one-ace/2521240#2521240).  You will notice that I accounted for which player receives which card, not the order in which they are received.  In the second approach (the book's approach), the order of the cards is considered.  Even if you treat the problem as dividing the deck into four piles of $13$ cards, you can always label the piles to distinguish between them, which makes counting easier.

Comment: I should add that you distributed all the cards in the denominator, then divided by the $4!$ ways the same sets of cards could have been distributed to each player.  In your numerator, you have to count the number of ways all the cards can be distributed to the players in such a way that each player receives one ace (your missing factor of $4!$), then divide by the $4!$ ways the same sets of cards could have been distributed to each player.

Comment: Ah, that clarifies it. Thank you!

Comment: I have a follow-up question, if that's okay. I understand that there are 4! ways for four people to each receive an ace because the ace are distinct; person 1 receiving an ace of hearts is different from person 1 receiving an ace of spaces. But, suppose we have 4 kids and 4 chocolate bars that are all exactly the same. Isn't there only one way to hand out 4 chocolate bars since they're identical? So the probability everyone receives one chocolate bar each is $1/\binom{7}{3}$. Is this correct?

Comment: In probability problems, it pays to treat each object as distinct.  We can always label the indistinguishable chocolate bars to make them distinct.  Therefore, there are still $4^4$ events in our sample space and $4!$ ways to distribute our newly labeled chocolate bars to the four people.  The reason we treat the chocolate bars as labeled is to obtain a uniform distribution, that is, one in which each event is equally likely to occur.  By the way, I wrote a combinatorial answer to the conditional probability problem you posed yesterday.